# Eclipse Mosquitto Dynamic Security Plugin

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

One question I can't seem to find any docs about.
I have made a PHP API that uses the [Dynamic Security Plugin](https://mosquitto.org/documentation/dynamic-security/).

Is there any way I can map the pub with the response in the sub topic? As of now it returns in the response topic something like this:

```
"{"responses":[{"command":"createRole","error":"Role already exists"}]}"
```

But if I have multiple requests, it would be nice to have a way to map them together. For instance sending a ID on the publish that is returned in the corresponding response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hopefully, someone will answer it. I would suggest, due to the very specific nature of the question, to also buzz http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.mosquitto

Answer (score 0):

Using the Request-Response Pattern introduced in MQTT 5, you can provide response topic on each publish message. So that you can map the corresponding message topic to their response topics.

Comment: Think ? Is this a answer or a comment?